# Starting QEMU VM with USB serial device attached fails with permission denied, but attaching it after VM is started works

Tags: usb, kvm, qemu, libvirt, ttyusb

I have a defined a USB device like this in `virt/usb-serial.xml`:

```
    <serial type="dev">
      <source path="/dev/serial/by-id/usb-dresden_elektronik_ingenieurtechnik_GmbH_ConBee_II_DE2403534-if00"/>
      <target type="usb-serial" port="1">
        <model name="usb-serial"/>
      </target>
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="5"/>
    </serial>
```

I successfully attached it like this:

```
virsh # detach-device hass4 virt/usb-serial.xml --persistent
Device detached successfully
```

The VM was able to access the USB device perfectly fine. However after rebooting the host device the VM failed to boot because of this USB serial device:

```
virsh # start hass4
error: Failed to start domain 'hass4'
error: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2023-06-01T20:28:52.153257Z qemu-system-x86_64: -chardev serial,id=charserial1,path=/dev/serial/by-id/usb-dresden_elektronik_ingenieurtechnik_GmbH_ConBee_II_DE2403534-if00: Could not open '/dev/serial/by-id/usb-dresden_elektronik_ingenieurtechnik_GmbH_ConBee_II_DE2403534-if00': Permission denied
```

Detaching the device let the VM boot fine, but curiously right after booting I could successfully attach the device again:

```
virsh # detach-device hass4 virt/usb-serial.xml --persistent
Device detached successfully

virsh # start hass4
Domain 'hass4' started

virsh # attach-device hass4 virt/usb-serial.xml
Device attached successfully
```

Why does it fail on initial boot and how can I resolve the permission issue? For context I have defined this in `/lib/udev/rules.d/51-qemu-usb-passthrough.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1cf1" ATTRS{idProduct}=="0030" GROUP="libvirt"
```

with those being the corresponding vendor and product IDs for this device:

```
$ lsusb -d 1cf1:0030
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 1cf1:0030 Dresden Elektronik ZigBee gateway [ConBee II]
```

In `/etc/libvirt/qemu.conf` I have set:

```
user = "henrik"
group = "libvirt"
```

with `henrik` being the user I run these commands from.

Comment: Have you tried to launch `qemu` with appropriate device options: `qemu-system-x86_64 [...]  -device blabla` cf doc [here](https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/system/devices/usb.html).